# replace в конкретной таблице mysql, php

Tags: php, mysql

Этот код:

```
<?php
    $search_replace = array(
    'MAHLE FILTERS' => 'MAHLE FILTER',
    'FEBI' => 'FEBI BILSTEIN',
    'CONTI' => 'CONTITECH',
    'BluePrint' => 'BLUE PRINT',
    'FISCHER' => 'FA1',
    'Denso' => 'DENSO',
    'MAHLE ENGINE' => 'MAHLE ORIGINAL',
    'Monroe' => 'MONROE',
    'KAYABA' => 'KYB',
    'K-Flex' => 'KYB',
    'Wagner' => 'WAGNER',
    'MANN' => 'MANN-FILTER',
    'Purflux' => 'PURFLUX',
    'Elring' => 'ELRING',
    'Osram' => 'OSRAM',
    'WIX - Filtron' => 'WIX FILTERS',
    'VICTOR REINZ' => 'REINZ',
    'VALEO PHC' => 'VALEO',
    'Ruville' => 'RUVILLE',
    'Lemforder' => 'LEMFÖRDER',
    'LEMFORDER' => 'LEMFÖRDER',
    ',' => '.'
    );

    mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error());
    $show_tables = mysql_query( 'SHOW TABLES' );
    while( $st_rows = mysql_fetch_row( $show_tables ) ) {
        foreach( $st_rows as $cur_table ) {
            $show_columns = mysql_query( 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM ' . $cur_table );
            while( $cc_row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $show_columns ) ) {
                $column = $cc_row['Field'];
                $type = $cc_row['Type'];
                if( strpos( $type, 'char' ) !== false || strpos( $type, 'text' ) !== false ) {
                    foreach( $search_replace as $old_string => $new_string ) {
                        $replace_query = 'UPDATE ' . $cur_table .
                            ' SET ' .  $column . ' = REPLACE(' . $column .
                            ', \'' . $old_string . '\', \'' . $new_string . '\')';
                        mysql_query( $replace_query );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo 'заменено';
    mysql_free_result( $show_columns );
    mysql_free_result( $show_tables );
?>
```

заменяет значения во всей базе

Как ограничить замену только для одной конкретной таблицы

Comment: Да так и сделать: заменять только в одной таблице, а не во всех. В чём конкретно проблема?

Comment: while( $st_rows = mysql_fetch_row( $show_tables )) сюда допишите таблицу в которой надо заменять данные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например можно в цикл добавить проверку `if ($cur_table == 'НАЗВАНИЕ_ТАБЛИЦЫ')`, далее пример:

```
foreach( $st_rows as $cur_table ) {
    if ($cur_table == 'НАЗВАНИЕ_ТАБЛИЦЫ') {
        $show_columns = mysql_query( 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM ' . $cur_table );
        while( $cc_row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $show_columns ) ) {
            $column = $cc_row['Field'];
            $type = $cc_row['Type'];
            if( strpos( $type, 'char' ) !== false || strpos( $type, 'text' ) !== false ) {
                foreach( $search_replace as $old_string => $new_string ) {
                    $replace_query = 'UPDATE ' . $cur_table .
                        ' SET ' .  $column . ' = REPLACE(' . $column .
                        ', \'' . $old_string . '\', \'' . $new_string . '\')';
                    mysql_query( $replace_query );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Либо убрать лишнее и делать сразу по конкретной таблице:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error());

$cur_table = 'НАЗВАНИЕ_ТАБЛИЦЫ';
$show_columns = mysql_query( 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM ' . $cur_table );
while( $cc_row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $show_columns ) ) {
    $column = $cc_row['Field'];
    $type = $cc_row['Type'];
    if( strpos( $type, 'char' ) !== false || strpos( $type, 'text' ) !== false ) {
        foreach( $search_replace as $old_string => $new_string ) {
            $replace_query = 'UPDATE ' . $cur_table .
                ' SET ' .  $column . ' = REPLACE(' . $column .
                ', \'' . $old_string . '\', \'' . $new_string . '\')';
            mysql_query( $replace_query );
        }
    }
}

echo 'заменено';
mysql_free_result( $show_columns );
mysql_free_result( $show_tables );
```

Comment: Ага, "проще" наворотить лишнего кода и потом проверять условия. Вместо того, чтобы этот лишний код просто выкинуть :)

Comment: смысл бегать по всем таблицам когда надо заменить только в одной?

Comment: Добавил вариант без обхода всех таблиц

Comment: Да, спасибо, второй вариант куда лучьше.